# Character shift with spreadsheet

Tags: regex, libreoffice-calc, caesar-cipher

I want to basically do a Ceasar Cipher with LibreOffice Calc (same as Excel). I don't want to use macros and I'm trying to use only formulas. First I'm trying to get the ASCII code of each character of a string.

I tried with REGEX and I can't manage to get what I want. First I want to get the UNICODE of each character. I managed to get :

`=REGEX(K15,"([a-zA-Z])",UNICODE("$1"),"g")`

With K15 being where the text is which is "test".

I get as a result "36363636". I only get the code character of the dollar sign 4 times. What am I doing wrong ?

Thanks

Comment: I don't use LibreOffice but it's hard to imagine that it would be possible to pass a backreference to another function. Usually, backreferences can only be used as part of the pattern or replacement string. The `UNICODE()` function knows nothing about `$1` and just treats it like a normal string. Why can't you use macros? I imagine this would be trivial to implement in a user-defined function (which can still be called from a formula). Is that not good enough?

Comment: Also, why are you using `UNICODE()` instead of `ASC()` if you're only interested in `[a-zA-Z]`?

Comment: Perhaps a Caesar cipher with a fixed shift of 13 will suffice? In this case, use the [**ROT13( ) function**](https://wiki.documentfoundation.org/Documentation/Calc_Functions/ROT13)

Comment: Thank you for your answers ! I know with macro it would be easy. The document will then be shared on other computers and it would be easy not to modify the macro security panel on each computer to allow the macro. That's why I wanted to use only formulas.
I didn't know about "ASC()" but it seems to do nothing on my computer. I have version 7.4.6.2. 
To answer JohnSUN, ROT13() is great unfortunaltely I would like rotation of any number.

Comment: I don't find a function REGEX in Excel, so it seems LibreOffice Calc isn't _same as Excel_.

Comment: @41686d6564standsw.Palestine: You're thinking of `CODE()`. There is an `Asc()` but it's used in Basic macros, not spreadsheet formulas.

Comment: @JimK Ah, you're right. I had just checked the docs and found an `Asc()` function but didn't pay attention that it was for basic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you didn't mention any requirement about limiting to a single formula, we can do this with helper columns. To start off, I added the shift distance in K16, using 7 as an example.

Now in L15, add the following formula to extract the first letter. Fill down to L18 by dragging. (The `ROW()` functions are for convenience — you could simply change the values to 1, 2, 3, and 4 instead).

```
=MID(K$15;1+ROW()-ROW(K$15);1)
```

Next comes the big formula in M15 that does most of the work. Fill down to M18.

```
=IF(CODE(L15)+K$16>CODE("z");CHAR(CODE(L15)+K$16-CODE("z")+CODE("a")-1);CHAR(CODE(L15)+K$16))
```

The formula converts to code point and then adds the shift distance. If it goes past the code point of z, then wrap around to the code point of a. Finally, convert the code point back to the character.

When that is done, simply add `=TEXTJOIN(;;M15:M18)` to get the result, which yields `alza`. I put it in K17.

[image: result "alza"]

Comment: Thank you for your answer ! It works for want I wanted. Not the perfect solution but it's a nice workaround for this problem.

Comment: I've changed the formula to `=MID(K$15;ROW(A1);1)` to get just the increment of 1 each time and dragged the thing to cell number 2000 just in case. It's kinda clunky but it's fine.
I also added REGEX to the big formula like this the shift just applies to a-ZA-Z and not spaces and special characters :
`=REGEX(L15,"[a-zA-Z]",IF(CODE(L15)+K$16>CODE("z");CHAR(CODE(L15)+K$16-CODE("z")+CODE("a")-1);CHAR(CODE(L15)+K$16)))` 
For the TEXTJOIN i've put =`TEXTJOIN(;;M15:M2000)`

Comment: If you're matching `/A-Z/` then you'll want to handle those as well — `CODE("a")` only works for lowercase. A few options here: remove `/A-Z/` from the regex if it's not needed, cast everything to lowercase, or expand the formula to perform uppercase shifting.